# Fill a specific column in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, api, datagrid

i've a datagrid and an observable collection filled with data from an API.

I created an hyperlink column in my datagrid and i would like to fill this specific column with data from my observable collection. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataGrid is row based. You would need to iterate over your `ItemsSource` collection and set a specific property that corresponds to the column. The column should be bound to said property of course.

Comment: Do you have an idea about which code I could use to do it ? How can I select specific data from an observable collection ?

Comment: That's a different question and fairly basic. Search stackoverflow or google, there are various ways of doing that, including LINQ.

Comment: What i want to do is select links data from my collection and then insert them into a specific column in my datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to select data from my ObservableCollection, a LINQ request seems to be the best way.

```
var filtreditems = from games in App.ApiGamesList //(my observable collection)
select games.api_detail_url;
```

Then i try to put the result into a datagrid :

```
mydatagrid.ItemsSource = filtreditems;
```

The problem is, instead of showing an URL in datagrid's rows, it shows a column with title "Length" and the lenght of the url in each rows.

Comment: Could someone help me to understand why my datagrid only show a length column with the number of letters of each URL and not the URL itself when i use this LINQ request ? If i do :

 `foreach ( var games in App.ApiGamesList )
            {
                mastring = mastring + "-" + games.api_detail_url;        
            }
            MessageBox.Show(mastring);`

I get a string with URLS.